How to dynamically render a Laravel Blade component with JavaScript variables?
I am trying to dynamically render a Laravel Blade component using JavaScript variables. Specifically, I am passing the label and color properties from JavaScript into a Blade component like this:
<x-badge label="${customer.status.label}" color="${customer.status.color}" />

However, this approach doesn’t work as expected. The component itself is working fine, and the label property renders as expected. However, the color property is not being rendered correctly.
I confirmed that the ${customer.status.color} variable contains the correct value.
I expected the color to dynamically apply the correct badge class based on the JavaScript variable, but only the label shows up, while the color is setting the default that i defined.

Blade code is processed on the server by PHP/Laravel when the page is first requested. The completed HTML output of that processing is then passed to the browser for rendering. JavaScript code runs in the browser, once your page has been delivered from the server and loaded into it. Therefore it cannot execute until the blade code has already finished executing. So you can't feed JS  variables to blade in the manner that I think you're imagining. You seem to have somewhat misunderstood the lifecycle of a web page.

If you want to use JS to change the appearance of a HTML element after the page has loaded (and perhaps some other event has occurred which would cause the JS to run? It's not clear from your description what actually triggers the JS code you're referring to) thhen you can certainly do that, but you need to use the usual JS DOM functions to achieve it. That has nothing to do with laravel or blade.

I get it now, and I was just curious if there was a workaround. I’ll probably use Tailwind variables to do something similar. The issue was I was trying to do PHP logic inside the component. Appreciate the help!

I'm not familiar with tailwind specifically but yes potentially that might be an approach. The key thing to remember is you can use JS to act on the HTML elements which get rendered to the browser. The functions for doing that are well-documented on places like MDN and elsewhere, and are the subject of many, many online tutorials and examples too.
